# Output of the greedy algorithm in C doesn't give me any output

Tags: c, cs50

I'm on week 2 of CS50 and am currently struggling with applying the theory to the actual work. I've been trying to do it in different ways when it gave me errors and I've come to this code.

However, it isn't giving me an error code any more. Instead, there is just no output. I don't understand what I've done wrong as it makes sense in my head. What can I try next?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int coins_used = 0;
    float owed_to_customer = 0.0;
    int q = 25;
    int d = 20;
    int n = 5;
    int p = 1;

    do {
        owed_to_customer = get_float("How much is owed?: \n");
    }

    while (owed_to_customer < 0);

    int cents = round(owed_to_customer * 100);

    while (cents > q)

        coins_used = (cents / q);
    cents = (cents % q);

    if (cents == 0)

        printf("%d\n", coins_used);

    while (cents > d)

        coins_used = coins_used + (cents / d);
    cents = cents + (cents % d);

    if (cents == 0)

        printf("%d\n", coins_used);

    while (cents > n)

        coins_used = coins_used + (cents / n);
    cents = cents + (cents % n);

    if (cents == 0)
        printf("%d\n", coins_used);

    while (cents > p)

        coins_used = coins_used + (cents / p);
    cents = cents + (cents % p);

    if (cents == 0)
        printf("%d\n", coins_used);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging ?

Comment: Did you try debugging? while loop can be infinite.

Comment: @rohanBari since the missing or wrong indentation is part of the problem, I would not fix it in the question. please undo your edit.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Okay, I've rolled back to the prevision revision.

Answer (score 1):

The while statement loops over one statement. E.g. in

```
while (cents > q)
coins_used = (cents / q);    <== only this statement is inside the loop
cents = (cents % q);         <== after the loop
```

therefore `cents` never gets updated and the while loop runs forever!

When you want to loop over several statements, you must enclose them in braces

```
while (cents > q) {
    coins_used = (cents / q);
    cents = (cents % q);
}
```

---

```
while (owed_to_customer < 0);
```

loops over nothing, since you have added a semicolon denoting an empty statement.

---

There is a visually orphaned while here

```
do {
    owed_to_customer = get_float("How much is owed?: \n");
}

while (owed_to_customer < 0);
```

it belongs to the do-loop. Write it like this, to make this visually apparent

```
do {
    owed_to_customer = get_float("How much is owed?: \n");
} while (owed_to_customer < 0);
```

See also: [Use braces for the body of an if, for, or while statement](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP19-C.+Use+braces+for+the+body+of+an+if%2C+for%2C+or+while+statement).
The introduction says:

> Opening and closing braces for if, for, and while statements should always be used even if the statement's body contains only a single statement.
> [...]
> Braces improve the uniformity and readability of code. More important, when inserting an additional statement into a body containing only a single statement, it is easy to forget to add braces because the indentation gives strong (but misleading) guidance to the structure.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer! It stopped looping, thank God. However, I get as output 

0
0
0
0

after updating my code. Do you perhaps know the cause for this?

Comment: As other said already, debug your code! I.e., place a break point at the beginning and single-step through it, inspect the variables and see what happens.

Comment: @ano `cents = cents + (cents % d);` looks wrong. Isn't `cents` supposed to be keeping track of the money left after extracting as many coins of the current face value as possible? I think it should be `cents = cents % d;`. Same for `n` and `p`.